# Getting element text with webdriver

Tags: webdriver

I would like to get a node's text without also getting its children's text.  E.g. how do I get the text "hello" from the following HTML?

```
<div id="myid">hello <b>world</b></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've been able to make this work is by using reflection to bypass the WebElement's visibility protection:

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElementById("myid");
Method getter = webElement.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getElement");
getter.setAccessible(true);
HtmlElement htmlElement = (HtmlElement) getter.invoke(webElement);
String name = htmlElement.getFirstChild().getTextContent();
```

Comment: why not to just execute javascript? like `driver.executeScript("return document.getElementById('myid').firstChild.nodeValue")`?

Comment: I tried that, but I then had to set "driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true)" which slowed my program down tremendously.

Comment: Then you should probably look into why it slowed down so much. Is it slow hardware? (maybe it's time for an upgrade). In my opinion, the web-site without javascript is not really a web-site :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the XPath-expression

```
//div[@id='myid']/text()
```

for all text nodes directly under that div, and

```
//div[@id='myid']/text()[k]
```

for the k-th text node under that div.

I have tested this XPaths with XSL using libxslt, but not in the webdriver (but I know webdriver supports XPath).

Comment: I already have the WebElement for the div, so I'm guessing the XPath expression I'd want is something like "./text()[0]", but I can't figure out how to make it work with WebDriver.

Comment: In XPath indices start at 1, is that your problem?

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that. Thanks! Still doesn't seem you can do this with webdriver though: The xpath expression './a/text()' selected an object of type 'class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomText' instead of a WebElement